# About inequalities (NBHM-2012)

Tags: inequality

Prove the following inequalities:

1. $\arctan x$  $> $${\frac{x}{1+x^2}}$
2. $\ln(1+x)$ $>$ ${\frac{x}{1+x}}$

Can anyone help me get started?

Comment: Find a point they agree and use derivative to figure out Left hand side-Right hand side increasing or decreasing

Comment: Start with the intgeral representation of either function, and use the trivial lower bound. For instance, $\arctan x = \int_0^x \frac{1}{1+t^2} \mathrm{d}t$. Note that for $|t| <|x|, 1 + t^2 < 1 + x^2$. Thus, $\arctan x > \frac{1}{1+x^2} \int_0^x \mathrm{d}t$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints:**
$$1+t^2 \geqslant 1-t^2 \implies \int_0^x  \frac{dt}{1+t^2} \geqslant \int_0^x\frac{1-t^2}{(1+t^2)^2}dt$$

$$1+t \geqslant 1 \implies \int_0^x\frac{dt}{1+t} \geqslant \int_0^x\frac{dt}{(1+t)^2}$$

Comment: Question seems a bit different to me...how to get to that question from answer?

Comment: @PranitaGupta - complete the integrations, what do you get?